# Is the Common Name mandatory for digital certificates?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority

I'm working on a project, where we use the **Common Name** as a certificate's basic identifier. However, importing certificates without the **Common Name** fails.

What's the default way to use digital certificates? Which identifier should we choose to be able to import them?

Comment: Import in what ?

Comment: @Stephane
Import Digital certificates which is not having CN name.

Comment: Again: Import **in** what (not "import what")

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as [X.509](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280) is concerned, the Common Name is not mandatory. However, a number of systems will use the CN for display purposes, e.g. most "certificate manager" GUI in Windows. Therefore, it is recommended, if only for ease of sysadmin tasks, to include reasonably precise CN in certificates.

If you want to, from an application, pinpoint a specific certificate, then the good identifier to use is the "thumbprint", which really is a hash of the certificate. As long as the hash function is collision-resistant (Microsoft uses SHA-1, which is still quite robust in that respect), no two distinct certificates will exhibit the same thumbprint.

The "standard X.509" method of referencing a specific certificate is to use the pair *issuerDN + serial number*. Only the combination of both values is (supposedly) unique; serial numbers alone don't cut it. Mind that I am talking about the *issuer's* name, not the *subject's*; and this is the whole DN, not just the CN part of it. Moreover, it is allowed for a certificate to have an empty `issuerDN` provided it also contains an `Issuer Alt Name` extension with the complete DN. This means that properly using the issuer+serial pair can be somewhat complex. The thumbprint is easier.

Answer (score 3):

In case of HTTPS protocol, *Common Name* can also be used by some of the client applications for verification of the server's identity. The RFC [2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818) says the following about the server's identity:

> If a subjectAltName extension of type dNSName is present, that MUST be
> used as the identity. Otherwise, the (most specific) Common Name field
> in the Subject field of the certificate MUST be used. Although the use
> of the Common Name is existing practice, it is deprecated and
> Certification Authorities are encouraged to use the dNSName instead.

This means that, in case of HTTPS protocol, servers should use the *subjectAltName* as the main source of identifier and support the *Common Name* for backward compatibility.